# jQuery: unwrap divs while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 4 divs. By default, the first one is "unwrapped"/"open" (it's `height` is `600px`). The others below have `height 40px`.

```
div:nth-child(1) {background-color:#cacaca;height:600px}
div:nth-child(2) {background-color:#e5ac30;height:40px}
div:nth-child(3) {background-color:#414042;height:40px}
div:nth-child(4) {background-color:#eaeaea;height:40px}
```

How can I "unwrap" (i.e. set its `height` to `600px`) the second `div` while scrolling (for example after scrolling `260px`), then unwrap the third one (when scrolled `500px`) and so on? The divs height should increase gently while scrolling, with an animation (not just `height:40px->height:600px`).

Here's a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/65s11L11/1/) with the 4 divs, with just the first "unwrapped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to `window.scroll()`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

and use JQuery `animate`  to expand your div

- http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Or CSS `transitions` and jquery `addclass` to expand your div

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
- http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/65s11L11/2/

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { 
    height: 40px;    
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: height 2s;
}
div.expanded { 
    height:600px;        
}
div:nth-child(1) {background-color:#cacaca;}
div:nth-child(2) {background-color:#e5ac30;}
div:nth-child(3) {background-color:#414042;}
div:nth-child(4) {background-color:#eaeaea;}
```

**JQuery**

```
$($('div').get(0)).addClass('expanded');
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var x = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(x > 125) {
        $($('div').get(1)).addClass('expanded');
    }
});
```